# Disconnect old app with a page and connect new app with the same page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-audience-network

I have a **old-app** and it is connected to our facebook page **X**. I created a **new-app**.

Now I want to disconnect my **old-app** and page **X**.

Then I want to connect my **new-app** and page **X**

When I mean connection, The adplacements which I have created on my new  should be available on my page. If you navigate

**Facebook Page -> Publishing tools -> Monetization -> Recirculation Ads ->** I should see my new apps adplacement id to be there and my old adplacement ID's should not be there.

**NOTE:**
I also tried to connect to page straight way by adding tab option as described in other questions. `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=appid&display=popup&next=http://www.example.com` I get only different kind of errors like

```
This application does not support integration with your profile.
```

When I tried replacing mysite.com with my facebook page url like

https://www.facebook.com/pagename I got

```
An error occurred. Please try again later.
```

Comment: Explain what exactly you mean by “connect” ...?

Comment: The adplacements which I have created should be available on my page I mean 

Publishing tools -> Monetization -> Recirculation Ads -> I should see my new apps adplacement id to be there and my old adplacement ID's should not be there.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on My experience what I understand is you can not create a new app and make it connect to a page. If you want a new app for your page, delete your old app, then enable audience network on

FB page -> Publishing Tools -> Monetization -> Enable Audience network.

It will automatically create a app for you create placement and other setup in that app. Now you have a new app connected to your page.